# Yii2 User Registration with Google

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I am using Yii2 User module for managing users in my Yii2 project. I have enabled authentication with Google and Facebook. I can login with Google and Facebook, but cannot register a new user with social authentication. It looks like it was possible in previous versions of yii2 user according to this. (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-google-authentication--cms-24987)
However the registration form does not have the links anymore. Isn't this possible now?

PS I have  "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev", in my composer

Comment: Check if registration is enabled.

Comment: registration is enabled.  Users can register themselves, but cannot use Google/Fb to do so.